# Creating a grass area with an irregular boundary on top of some uneven terrain

Tags: modeling

I am a Blender beginner, and I am trying to create some terrain with a grass area on top of it. Both the outer boundary of the terrain and the grass are are irregular shapes.

I have created the underlying terrain by defining some key points on the topology, as well as the two boundaries as below, and then used knife project to cut the outline:

[image]

Now, to add the grass area, I first tried to duplicate the terrain, and then cut it to the shape of the grass. The problem with this is that I cannot go back later and edit the terrain's displacement, whilst also having the grass follow it still.

So instead, I am trying to use the Shrinkwrap modifier, because it seems to do the right thing:

[image]

It seems like the two meshes used in Shrinkwrap need to be commensurate, otherwise they don't overlap properly. It gets better if I use Subdivide on the planes first:

[image]

[image]

Is the best approach for something like this in Blender really to subdivide so much? There are a lot of polygons in the model now. (I would like to create the grass with a hair particle system next, so it could end up being intensive to work with). I am wondering if there is a better way - perhaps not using Shrinkwrap?

Comment: Can't you just add the particle grass to the terrain that you have? Why do you want to shrinkwrap one mesh on top of another? Weight paint (requires some geometry=subdivisions) or a texture to define where the grass grows should do the trick.

Comment: @Blunder Interesting, I didn't think about this... How do you use a texture to choose where the grass should be? Do you mean use an existing image somehow?

Comment: Yes, you can paint an image texture and use it in the *Texture Properties* tab (the last tab on the right side). Use UV mapping here. The texture can have an influence on the particles, e.g. *Density*. In the *Particle Properties* tab, you can use the texture for the particles. The image texture also can be used for the shader to colorize the mesh and the particles => https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxrjb.jpg